# Access docker build context inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have multiple projects/folders inside a single directory called `root`. There is a common Dockerfile that runs all projects/folders. I run the projects passing different build context in docker build command as below:

```
$ docker build -t project1:1.0.0 -f . root/project1
$ docker build -t project2:1.0.0 -f . root/project2
$ docker build -t project2:1.0.0 -f . root/project3
```

Now, I need to add some conditions based on docker build context in dockerfile. Can that be done? I didn't find a way to get docker build context.

Comment: That depends on what you want to test for and what you want to do based on the test

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the project name to the Dockerfile as an argument and build for instance:

```
ARG ENV

RUN if [ "$ENV" = "production" ] ; then yarn client:build:prod ; else yarn client:build ; fi
```

finally:
`docker build -t node-image .  --build-arg ENV=production`

Comment: yes, this is one possible solution, but I was thinking not pass any extra args in docker build as Im already passing different build context

Comment: Also I need to run a docker command in if condition. something like this `# RUN if [ "$SCRIPT_NUMBER" = "1" ] ; then COPY .prettierrc . ; else COPY .env .; fi1. Its not recognizing `COPY` command in `'if` condition

Comment: You can't conditionally do `COPY`.

Comment: @HansKilian correct.